# External Javascript is not working?Is there any specific folder for javascript

Tags: spring

I have applied an external javascript in my spring project but it is not working. If I apply the javascript internally then it is working. Also there is no error.

My code is

loginPage.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html>
<head>
     <title>Spring3Example</title>
<style>
  .error {
      color: #EF1313;
      font-style: italic;
  }
</style>


<!-- 
<script type="text/javascript">

function focusFieldOne() {
    document.form1.user.focus();
    }


function validateForm() 
{ 
    var str1=new String("filed should not be blank");
if(document.form1.user.value=="") 
{ 

    alert(str1.fontcolor("red"));
    //alert("User Name should not be blank.."); 
document.form1.user.focus(); 
return false; 
} 
else if(document.form1.password.value=="") 
{ 
alert("Password should not be blank"); 
document.form1.password.focus(); 
return false; 
} 
}

function func1()
{
    //alert("this is final alert");
     var user = document.getElementById('user').value;
      var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;

        if( /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test( user ) ) {
            alert('Input is not alphanumeric');
            return false;
        }



        if( /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test( pass ) ) {
            alert('Input is not alphanumeric');
            return false;
        }
        else
        return true;    

    }
</script> -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/script1.js"></script>


</head>
<body onLoad="focusFieldOne();">


<form:form name="form1" action="login.html" commandName="userDetails" onsubmit="func1()">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">User</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="user" /> <form:errors path="user"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">Password</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="password" type="password"  /> <form:errors path="password"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any specific folder to which javascript is to be added.

Answer (score 0):

The WEB-INF folder is not for 'public' files. First you have to specify the static resources you are serving (Spring MVC). From the docs:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/public-resources/");
}
```

The resources folder mentioned here should be in your web path (not WEB-INF).
For detailed information have a look at the docs http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources